# Cant calculate interactions using flashlight package with iris data in R?

Tags: r, mlr3

So Im trying to use the `flashlight` package with the iris data. One of the functions `flashlight` provides is to calculate the interactions between variables called `light_interaction`. I can get `light_interaction` to work if I use an `lm` model but I can not get it to work if I create my model using `mlr3` [side note: if I create a regression model using `mlr3`, it works perfectly with flashlights interaction function... I just can't get it to work for classification... and I need flashlight to work with mlr3 for my package]. In the code below I show an example of it working with an `lm` model... and an example of it not working with `mlr3`... am I doing something wrong?

`lm` model example that works:

```
library(flashlight)

fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)
x <- flashlight(model = fit, label = " ", data = iris, y = "Species")
light_interaction(x, pairwise = TRUE, type = "H", grid_size = 5,
                         normalize = F)
```

`mlr3` model that doesn't work:

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3learners)
# mlr3 TASK
bc_T = TaskClassif$new(id = "dat", backend = iris, target = "Species")
# learner
lrn = lrn("classif.ranger")
# model
bc_M <- lrn$train(bc_T)

x <- flashlight(model = bc_M, label = " ", data = iris, y = "Species")
light_interaction(x, pairwise = TRUE) # this line creates an error
```

This throws back an error saying:

> Error in rowsum.default(xx * ww, gg) : 'x' must be numeric In
> addition: Warning message: In Ops.factor(xx, ww) : ‘*’ not meaningful
> for factors

Answer (score 1):

mlr3 uses R6 and the fitted model is stored in the `$model` slot.
I do not know what `flashlight::light_interaction()` does but as far as your error is concerned, it is as simple as

```r
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3learners)
library(flashlight)
bc_T <- TaskClassif$new(id = "dat", backend = iris, target = "Species")
lrn <- lrn("classif.ranger")
bc_M <- lrn$train(bc_T)

x <- flashlight(model = bc_M$model, label = " ", data = iris, y = "Species")
print(x)
#> 
#> Flashlight   
#> 
#> Model:            Yes
#> y:            Species
#> w:            No
#> by:           No
#> data dim:         150 5
#> predict_fct default:  TRUE
#> linkinv default:  TRUE
#> metrics:      rmse
#> SHAP:             No
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. Just to be clear, the error isn't with creating the `flashlight` object. That is, `x <- flashlight(model = bc_M, label = " ", data = iris, y = "Species")` works fine... the error occurs when I try to use `light_interaction`. If I try your method it throws back an error saying: `Error: Input must be a vector, not a 'ranger.prediction' object.`

Comment: That error is not related to mlr3 AFAICS. You pass a raw `ranger` object that has no relation anymore to mlr3 - at least in my answer. I am wondering why there is no error when you pass the encapsulated mlr3 learner as shown in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I want clear. I agree that the error isn't related to mlr3. The error is with `light_interaction` from flashlight package. If I follow the same process as above for a regression model, then everything works fine. it's only classification where `light_interaction` fails while using mlr3.

Comment: Maybe its related to your wording but as you describe the issue, you state "while using mlr3". However mlr3 has no relation here, you pass a raw ranger object. The same error would occur if you fit a ranger model directly with the package. It might be helpful to be on point with the wording in such cases to avoid confusion :)

Comment: from the [flashlight vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flashlight/vignettes/flashlight.html#binary-classification) it can be concluded that binary targets need to be numerical. It seems flashlight is not suitable for multiclass problems. Additionally in the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flashlight/vignettes/mlr3.html) about using flashlight with mlr3 there are no classification examples.

Comment: Thanks @missuse for digging deep -  I did not have time for that :)